# Incorrect hard drive serial number

Tags: c#, wmi, hard-drive, serial-number

I am currently developing a program that will allow me to detect the serial number of all hard drives in a computer and display them as a barcode.

I have it working on my current machine (Windows 10) and it gets the correct serial numbers (same as what's on the hard drive label) but when I try and use it on a different machine (Windows 7) it just outputs a long string of numbers.

The program is able to detect and output the serial number on my usb fine.

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");

foreach (ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
{
    HardDrive hd = new HardDrive();

    hd.Model = wmi_HD["Model"].ToString();
    hd.SerialNum = Convert.ToString(wmi_HD.GetPropertyValue("SerialNumber"));

    hdCollection.Add(hd);
}
```

This is the current code I am using but the serial number it outputs is: 5635454d4338414e202020202020202020202020

I have tried `Win32_LogicalDrive` and `Win32_Volume` but they output the same string.

I have also tried this code snippet:

```
ManagementClass driveClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_DiskDrive");
ManagementObjectCollection drives = driveClass.GetInstances();

foreach (ManagementObject drive in drives)
{
    HardDrive hd = new HardDrive();
    
    hd.Model = drive["Name"].ToString();

    //hd.SerialNum = drive.GetPropertyValue("SerialNumber").ToString();

    hd.SerialNum = drive["SerialNumber"].ToString();
}
```

But this also does not work on the Windows 7 machine.

How could I fix my problem?

Comment: That looks like ascii in hex? is that what you are expecting? V5EMC8AN

Comment: there is a long discussion about this [on TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/0333dd28-3207-4df8-85c3-7ff540f98464/wmi-disk-serial-number?forum=ITCG). gist: its partly an inconsistency in WMI, and partly just the way manufacturers choose to store the SNs: hex-string SNMP-style, or plain.

Comment: Almost the serial number is 5VME8CNA haha getting close though.

Comment: yeah that swapping of digits is also mentioned in that article. it is due to endianness mismatch. also related: https://superuser.com/a/498109/698590. what happens when you start `msinfo32.exe` from the command line and navigate to Components>Storage>Drives, are the SNs shown as you would expect them?

Comment: So I've tested the program with hard drives of different manufacturers and that seems to be the problem, not all the serial numbers are stored as plain text as you said. I'll have to test msinfo tomorrow.

Comment: Is there possibility a more reliable way to get the hard drive serial numbers?